# htaccess rewrite index folder to php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is my folder structure

```
test
-.htaccess
-app
--index.php
```

I want when I go to http://localhost/test/, it rewrite to test/app/index.php (no redirect)

My htaccess below. Now it work fine with url http://localhost/test/some/thing. With url http://localhost/test/, it still show files index of folder **test**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/app/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule is expressed in regexp, so wouldn't that make your dot an any character match? Did you try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ app/index.php [L]
```